# Ignoring Django Migrations in pyproject.toml file for Black formatter

Tags: python, django, regex, pre-commit.com, pyproject.toml

I just got [Black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and [Pre-Commit](https://pre-commit.com/) set up for my Django repository.

I used the default config for Black from the tutorial I followed and it's been working great, but I am having trouble excluding my migrations files from it.

Here is the default configuration I've been using:

`pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 79
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
    \.git
  | \.hg
  | \.mypy_cache
  | \.tox
  | \.venv
  | _build
  | buck-out
  | build
  | dist
)/
'''
```

I used [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to make sure that `^.*\b(migrations)\b.*$` matched `apps/examples/migrations/test.py`.

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 79
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
    \.git
  | \.hg
  | \.mypy_cache
  | \.tox
  | \.venv
  | _build
  | buck-out
  | build
  | dist
  | ^.*\b(migrations)\b.*$
)/
'''
```

When I add that regex line to my config file, and run `pre-commit run --all-files`, it ignores the `.git` folder but still formats the migrations files.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @ClarkSandholtz why are you not accepting any of the answer, or explain why they don't work for you?

Comment: @sinoroc the formatting of the migrations ended up not being that big of a deal, so I just didn't worry about fixing it for awhile. Sorry for being slow on this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add the migration exclusion to your `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file

```yaml
- id: black
  exclude: ^.*\b(migrations)\b.*$
```

Comment: There is a reason to configure your tools in pyproject.toml (and others) instead of `pre-commit`'s config: you wan't to configure them in one place and have it working in your IDE/CLI/whatever and not just in `pre-commit`.

Answer (score 9):

That's the solution to the problem: `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.black]
exclude = '''
/(
  | migrations
)/

'''
```

Comment: Can you pass the documentation on where you take this syntax under the exclude option? Is this part of TOML language or black? Couldn't find it in Black docs...

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember where I got this, it was already in my project :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this (note last line):

```
[tool.black]
line-length = 79
include = '\.pyi?$'
exclude = '''
/(
    \.git
  | \.hg
  | \.mypy_cache
  | \.tox
  | \.venv
  | _build
  | buck-out
  | build
  | dist
  | migrations
)/
'''
```

Answer (score 2):

Maintaining two different places for `exclude` config doesn't look good if avoidable and will not work well for the CI either (should you want to dry run black in the PR checks).
Adding the following works for the `pyproject.toml` and then you can run the same in the pre-commit hook and CI:

```
[tool.black]
...
exclude = '''

(
  /(
    ...
    | .+/migrations
  )/
)
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

to just extend the default exlusions (without adding the whole list), you can just do:

```
[tool.black]
extend-exclude = '''
/(
  | migrations
)/
'''
```